# Node connection pool and PostgreSQL search_path

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, connection-pooling

We are using Node with PostgreSQL for a multitenancy app. Connection pooling is implemented. Depending on the client(user id), we need to switch the schema. How can we ensure that the request from the same client always uses the same connection? If that is not done, won't there be a problem because search_path is set for a connection?

Comment: Are you using `pool.query(…)` or `client = await pool.connect(); … client.query(…) … client.release()`? Please post your code.

Comment: "because search_path is set for a connection" It is your code, it works the way you write it to work.  Every time you check out a connection from the pool, just set the search_path to be what you want it to be and that is what it will be.